# How to create a Numpy Matrix with a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, matrix

I am trying to construct a matrix with numpy using an array of random numbers called noise  with 4 values which should be multiplied with 8 different numbers from an array called "factor" resulting in 8 rows in the final matrix.

So the matrix should have 4 columns for each value in "noise" and 8 rows for each factor. 
I don't know how to achieve that.

This is the code I got so for:

```py
import numpy as np  
from numpy import random

n = 4
noise = np.random.normal(size=n)


matrix = np.zeros((8,n)) # Pre-allocate matrix
for i in range(1,8):
   matrix[:,i] = [[noise]*i]


print(matrix)
```

I get the error message:

```py
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: So `matrix` is (8,n) and `matrix[:,i]` is (n,) shape.  `noise` is (n,) shape.  But what is the shape of `[[noise]*i]`.  It's actually a list, but when turned into an array, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to construct is the *outer product*

```
n = 4
noise = np.random.normal(size=n)
noise
# array([ 2.39723122, -0.99797246, -0.14242618, -0.55921136])

m = 8
factor = np.random.randint(0,10,m)
factor
# array([0, 5, 7, 6, 7, 3, 8, 6])

np.outer(factor,noise)
# array([[ 0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.        ],
#        [11.98615612, -4.98986228, -0.71213089, -2.79605682],
#        [16.78061856, -6.98580719, -0.99698324, -3.91447955],
#        [14.38338734, -5.98783473, -0.85455707, -3.35526818],
#        [16.78061856, -6.98580719, -0.99698324, -3.91447955],
#        [ 7.19169367, -2.99391737, -0.42727853, -1.67763409],
#        [19.17784979, -7.98377964, -1.13940942, -4.47369091],
#        [14.38338734, -5.98783473, -0.85455707, -3.35526818]])
```

The "outer" operation exists for many binary ufuncs. Because outer multiplication

```
np.multiply.outer(factor,noise)
```

is so common it has its own function `outer`.

The outer operation (for multiplication or other ufuncs) is (for 1D operands) roughly equivalent to

```
np.multiply(*np.ix_(factor,noise))
```

If a reducing form (prod for multiply, sum for add, min for minimum, etc.) exists we can also write

```
np.prod(np.ix_(factor,noise))
```

Finally, (somewhat unrelated) in case of the product we can also use `einsum`:

```
np.einsum('i,j',factor,noise)
```

Though `einsum` is maybe overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this instead of using a loop:

```
matrix = np.random.normal(size=(1, n)) * np.arange(8).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Here, the left hand-side of the multiplication has the shape `(1, n)` while the right-hand side has the shape `(8, 1)`. So both of them will be broadcasted to the shape `(8, n)` and then an element-wise multiplication is performed.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: n = 4 
    ...: noise = np.random.normal(size=n)                                                                    
In [13]: noise                                                                                               
Out[13]: array([-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219])
```

Let's look at what you are trying to assign - for specific `i`:

```
In [14]: np.array([[noise]*1])                                                                               
Out[14]: array([[[-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219]]])
In [15]: np.array([[noise]*2])                                                                               
Out[15]: 
array([[[-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219],
        [-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219]]])
In [16]: np.array([[noise]*3])                                                                               
Out[16]: 
array([[[-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219],
        [-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219],
        [-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219]]])
```

You are applying the `*3` to a list - which means 'replicate':

```
In [17]: [[noise]*3]                                                                                         
Out[17]: 
[[array([-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219]),
  array([-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219]),
  array([-1.93374989, -1.16536624,  0.42338714, -2.39942219])]]
```

The shapes are (1,1,4), (1,2,4), (1,3,4) etc.  Brackets in Python create a list; don't use them casually.  But

```
In [21]: np.zeros((8,4))[:,1].shape                                                                          
Out[21]: (8,)
```

you are trying to put each in a size (8,) slot.

Did you instead want to multiply the values of `noise` by `i`?

```
matrix = np.zeros((8,n)) # Pre-allocate matrix
for i in range(8):
   matrix[i,:] = noise*i
```

should work, properly matching the `matrix[i,:]` slot with the source, `noise`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. What can I do if the values of i are not in the range of (0,8) but come also from an array with random numbers. The following doesn't work: ```python 

noise_fac = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8])

b = 0.66

noise = rice.rvs(b, size=n)

matrix = np.zeros((8,n)) # Pre-allocate matrix
for i in (noise_fac):
   matrix[i,:] = noise*i
    
print(matrix) ```

Comment: It''s not easy to read code in a comment.  Can't you index `noise_fac` like you do `matrix`?  Or adapt @GZ0's answer?